# How to pass arguments in a java action within an oozie workflow?

Tags: java, oozie, oozie-workflow

I'm trying to create a Oozie workflow with one action, a java action to launch a program to parse an excel file inside HDFS, so, in order to this java program parse the file I need to pass it the location of the file, without the oozie workflow I just call the jar file with the arguments I need like:

```
   java -jar myJarFile.jar hdfs:///path/to/the/file.xlsx
```

Now in the java action inside the oozie workflow I need to write something like:

```
<action name="parse-file">
 <java>
  <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
  <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
  <main-class>parseFile</main-class>
  <arg>path/to.the/file.xlsx</arg>
  <file>lib/myJarFile.jar#myJarFile.jar</file>
 </java>
 <ok to="sen-success-email"/>
 <error to="failed-notification-email"/>
</action>
```

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 1):

- The java action will execute the `public static void main(String[] args)` of your class. Make sure you use fully specified package name. For example `a.b.c.MainClass`
- You don't need the `<file>` tag if you store `myJarFile.jar` in a `lib` directory next your `workflow.xml` on HDFS. For example:

```
workflow_dir/workflow.xml
workflow_dir/lib
workflow_dir/lib/myJarFile.jar
```

- Make sure you also upload all dependencies with your workflow.

References:

- Description of the Java action: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.6_Java_Action
- Sample workflow xml for a Java action: https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/examples/src/main/apps/java-main/workflow.xml#L30

Comment: All right, this is helpful, just one thing, for example I'm running this jar file from the command line: `java -cp FileProcessosSQL.jar:'hadoop classpath':'hdfs classpath':'hbase classpath' com.kata.team1.ProcessSQL SqlInsertion.sql` Just to be clear about it, in my folder `workflow/lib` I should put the libraries that are in `hadoop class path`, `HDFS class path` and `hbase class path ` ?

Comment: That should work. Alternatively, you could also upload dependencies to HDFS, and use ``oozie.libpath=/path/to/jars,another/path/to/jars`` in ``job.properties`` or define your own sharelib.